# MySQL User Variable within Expression Works for MySQL 8.0.28 and Onwards

Tags: mysql

In MySQL 8.0.23, I noticed that when I use a user variable like this (note this is not the real query)...

```
mysql> set @row = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select @row := @row + 1;
+------------------+
| @row := @row + 1 |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I would get this warning:

```
| Warning | 1287 | Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.
```

In fact, without converting this to a common table expression, a more complicated version of the above query will not give the proper result.

But when I tested this starting on MySQL 8.0.28 and onwards, I don't get this warning anymore and in fact the original query works again! I was looking at the [release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-28.html) and I could not see where this was actually reverted back. Does anyone know where I can get more information when this specific behavior was changed or reverted back?

Comment: Use ```SELECT @row + 1 INTO @row;``` instead.

Comment: *when I tested this starting on MySQL 8.0.28 and onwards, I don't get this warning anymore* You have cleared this warning. For example by the query executed after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=104918

The release notes for 8.0.28 mention the fix:

> When a condition was pushed down, the result of evaluating assignments to user variables in the SELECT list of the subquery were sometimes affected. For this reason, we now prevent condition pushdown for statements with assignments to user variables.

You mention that in your case "a more complicated version of the query" will not give the correct result. I assume the query that is wrong involves a subquery.

Besides this bug, in MySQL 8.0, you should use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function instead of user variables to produce a row number.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For simple expressions, `SET` works fine:

```
SET @row = @row + 1;
```

If you need to involve a table, say so.

(`:=` works in `SET`.  `=` means something different when used in `SELECT`.)

**From the Changelog** 2018-10-22 8.0.13 General Availability -- -- Important Change -----

> Setting user variables in statements other than
> [SET](/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html) is now deprecated due to
> issues that included those listed here:
>
> The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables was
> undefined.
>
> The default result type of a variable is based on its type at the
> beginning of the statement, which could have unintended effects when a
> variable holding a value of one type at the beginning of a statement
> was assigned a new value of a different type in the same statement.
>
> HAVING, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY clauses, when referring to a variable
> that was assigned a value in the select expression list, did not work
> as expected because the expression was evaluated on the client and so
> it was possible for stale column values from a previous row to be
> used.
>
> Syntax such as SELECT @var, @var:=@var+1 is still accepted in MySQL
> 8.0 for backward compatibility, but is subject to removal in a future release.

Comment: yes, that SELECT would have a table involved. I was just showing that that warning was removed from 8.0.28 and onwards and I hoping that someone knows where I can find more information why it was removed because it was not in the release notes.

Comment: @bichonfrise74 - I added the note with 8.0.13 2 years ago.